# Laravel checkbox stores 0 whatever value the user enters

Tags: jquery, laravel

Current, I am working on a Laravel-5.8 project. I am using data-bootstrap-switch checkbox in dynamic input field

[image: leave diagram]

Request Rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'leave_type_name' => [
             'required', 
             'string',
             'min:3',
             'max:80',                 
            Rule::unique('hr_leave_types')->where(function ($query) {
           return $query->where('leave_type_name', $this->leave_type_name)
              ->where('company_id', $this->company_id);
        })                
        ],     
        'leave_type_code' => [
             'nullable', 
             'string',
             'max:10',                 
            Rule::unique('hr_leave_types')->where(function ($query) {
           return $query->where('leave_type_code', $this->leave_type_code)
              ->where('company_id', $this->company_id);
        })                
        ],    
                                      
        'employee_type_id'           => 'required|array', 
        'employee_type_id.*' => [
             'required',  
           
        ],    
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
public function store(StoreLeaveTypeRequest $request)
{ 
    $leavetype = new HrLeaveType();
    $leavetype->leave_type_name             = $request->leave_type_name;
    $leavetype->leave_type_code             = $request->leave_type_code;

   $leavetype->save();        

    foreach ($request->employee_type_id as $key => $employee_type_id){

   $insert_array = [
        'employee_type_id'                  => $request->employee_type_id[$key],    
        'weekend_inclusive'                 => $request->weekend_inclusive[$key] ?? 0,
        'holiday_inclusive'                 => $request->holiday_inclusive[$key] ?? 0,
        'leave_type_id'                     => $leavetype->id,
     ];

      HrLeaveTypeDetail::create($insert_array );

       } 
    }
```

view

```
   <form  action="{{route('leave.leave_types.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       
       
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">  
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Leave Type Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="text" name="leave_type_name" value="{{ old('leave_type_name', $leavetype->leave_type_name) }}" placeholder="Enter leave type name" class="form-control @error('leave_type_name') is-invalid @enderror">
                @error('leave_type_name')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror                 
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Leave Type Code:</label>
              <input  type="text" name="leave_type_code" value="{{ old('leave_type_code', $leavetype->leave_type_code) }}" placeholder="Enter leave typecode" class="form-control @error('leave_type_code') is-invalid @enderror">
                @error('leave_type_code')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror                 
            </div>
          </div>                
            
            
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="description" class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{old('description',$leavetype->description)}}" placeholder="Enter Description here ...">{{old('description',$leavetype->description)}}</textarea>
                @error('description')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror                 
            </div>
          </div>

   <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Employee Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">Weekend Inclusive</th>
                            <th scope="col">Holiday Inclusive</th>   
                            <th scope="col"><a class="btn btn-info addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="40%">                    
                                <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Employee Type" tabindex="1" name="employee_type_id[]">
                                    <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Employee Type</option>
                                     @if($employeetypes->count() > 0 )
                                        @foreach($employeetypes as $employeetype)
                                         <option name="employee_type_id[]"  value="{{$employeetype->id}}">{{$employeetype->employee_type_name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif                                         
                                </select>
                            </td>                                                         
                            <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="weekend_inclusive[]"  class="form-control weekend_inclusive" value="{{old('weekend_inclusive') ? 'checked' : '' }}" unchecked data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="NO" data-on-text="YES"></td>
                            <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="holiday_inclusive[]"  class="form-control holiday_inclusive" value="{{old('holiday_inclusive') ? 'checked' : '' }}" unchecked data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="NO" data-on-text="YES"></td>                                
                            <td width="5%"><a class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                         </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.addRow').on('click', function () {
            addRow();

        });
        function addRow() {
            var addRow = '<tr>\n' +
'   <td width="40%"><select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Employee Type" tabindex="1" name="employee_type_id[]">\n' +
       '             <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Employee Type</option>\n' +
       '              @if($employeetypes->count() > 0 )\n' +
       '                 @foreach($employeetypes as $employeetype)\n' +
       '                 <option value="{{$employeetype->id}}">{{$employeetype->employee_type_name}}</option>\n' +
        '                 @endforeach\n' +
        '             @endif\n' +
        '         </select></td>\n' +
        '        <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="weekend_inclusive[]" class="form-control weekend_inclusive" value="{{old('weekend_inclusive') ? 'checked' : '' }}" unchecked data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="NO" data-on-text="YES"></td>\n' +
       '        <td width="10%"><input type="checkbox" name="holiday_inclusive[]" class="form-control holiday_inclusive" value="{{old('holiday_inclusive') ? 'checked' : '' }}" unchecked data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="NO" data-on-text="YES"></td>\n' +
'   <td width="5%"><a   class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>\n' +
'         </tr>';
            $('tbody').append(addRow);
            addRemoveListener();
        };
    addRemoveListener();
 });
</script>
```

I am using bootstrap switch checkbox. The checkbox can either be 0 or 1

0=No and 1=Yes

I am using dynamic input fields. When I submitted, What I observed is that whatever the user selects for:

```
    weekend_inclusive
    holiday_inclusive
```

the application stores 0 for both:

```
    weekend_inclusive
    holiday_inclusive
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

make sure to put that column in the `$fillable` of your model class

```
protected $fillable = [ 'checkbox_column' ];
```

Comment: it is there in the fillable

Answer (score 0):

Actually if the checkboox is checked you will receive as 'on'. Not '1' or 'true' or 'yes' . So write your code as

```
  $request->weekend_inclusive[$key] ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I use tinyint(1) for the datatype. 0 for Not/False and 1 for True/Yes. Kindly check my view blade, is it okay as I have written the      weekend_inclusive and holiday_inclusive. Or what else do I need to do?

Comment: @RahmiRanjanSahoo - I got this error    ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Http\Controllers\Leave\LeaveTypesController.php:98   when I did $request->weekend_inclusive[$key] ? 1 : 0;   and it points to:   'holiday_inclusive'                => $request->holiday_inclusive[$key] ? 1 : 0,

Answer (score 0):

Please check your "employee_type_id[]" which you are using inside select element name and again inside foreach loop option element. This is creating an issue. Please fix that.

```
<select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Employee Type" tabindex="1" name="employee_type_id[]">
        <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Employee Type</option>
               @if($employeetypes->count() > 0 )
                  @foreach($employeetypes as $employeetype)
                       <option name="employee_type_id[]"  value="{{$employeetype->id}}">{{$employeetype->employee_type_name}}</option>
                  @endforeach
               @endif                                         

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the name from option element Its not needed. You can fetch the selected option from the name what you have given in select element.

```
<select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Employee Type" tabindex="1" name="employee_type_id[]">
            <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Employee Type</option>
                   @if($employeetypes->count() > 0 )
                      @foreach($employeetypes as $employeetype)
                           <option value="{{$employeetype->id}}">{{$employeetype->employee_type_name}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                   @endif                                         
    </select>
```

Comment: @RashmianjanSahoo - If I remove employee_type_id how do I now do the freach in the controller

Comment: Are you aware of how to get the selected option value in controller ?? You can retrive by giving the name in select field not the name in option element. You can retrieve your selected option from the name what you have mentioned in select element.